# Play Framework stay on same page then changing language

Tags: java, scala, playframework, routes, http-headers

I am using play framework with java

I would like to ask you a question, if it is possible to get route method not url or path from Http Request, because i need to change some route parameter values to been able to open webpages in different language url. For example:

```
 POST    /namai.html                controllers.Application.postComment(String lng="ru")
 POST    /home.html                controllers.Application.postComment(String lng)

http://localhost:9000/en/namai.html **I would get bad request call**
http://localhost:9000/ru/namai.html **Page would open but link would be not the same language.**
```

I can't just replace language prefix, because I only been able to open url's in English language. Any ideas how to get route method from http request? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I already tried to parse route method from routes file depending on url, but no success there, because of url parameters in routes file. Tried to get information about route method from http request and no success there. I actually need a java method which would find a route method depending on url or path.

Comment: You should have a look at reverse routing

Comment: Could you help me understand what you are trying to do? It seems like you are trying to support actions in different languages? Maybe you could share the `postComment` action code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone collide with same kind of problem, easiest way to solve it is to use java reflection to call reverse routes class and activate needed method.